# get_userdata by username

Tags: users, api, rest-api

I am currently working with the REST API and have the need to `get_userdata()` but instead of the `user_id` I have the `username` I also have their email if that helps.

**Question:** Is this possible within the core functionality of WordPress? If not is there a round about way to get user info via username and then get the user_id from that to do the get_userdata call?

Comment: Use `get_user_by` function. [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`get_userdata()` function is an alias of `get_user_by('ID')` function. Use this code:

```
$username = 'your user name';
$user = get_user_by('login', $username);
```

It will return WP_User object on success, or false on failure. See [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/).

**REST API**: `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/<id>`